# Iterating over a dictionary while only printing once

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to get it to print the value only once. it seems to be printing it as many times as i have keys in the dict

```
movies = {
    '2005': ["Munich", "Steven Spielberg"],
    '2006': ["The prestige", "Christopher Nolan", "The Departed", "Martin Scorsese"],
    '2007': ["Into the Wild", "Sean Penn"]
    }


choice =input("Enter a year between 2005 and 2016:\n")

for i in movies:
    print(movies[choice],'\n')
```

my output for an entry of 2005 will be Munich, Steven Spielberg 3 times when i only need it once.

thanks

Comment: `for i in movies:` - if you only want to print the one that matches the input, why do you do this loop?

Comment: You say `for i in movies:`; that'll execute 3 times because the length of `movies` is 3. You're performing the same action 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop should be

```
for movie in movies[choice]:
    print(movie)
```

You are iterating over keys of dictionary - and since there are 3 keys, your line is printed 3 times

Answer (score 0):

it is normal because you loop over movies. If you want to have only once then you can do

```
choice =input("Enter a year between 2005 and 2016:\n")
print(movies[choice],'\n')
```